# Error add-repository on Deppin

Tags: linux, git

Hola muchachos estoy probando el OS Deepin y deseaba instalar el GIT pero solo instalaba una version antigua así que decidi agregar un repositorio:

```
$ add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 93, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Deepin/n/a
```

Espero su apoyo ya que soy nuevo en esto de probar sistemas operativos Linux en desarrollo.
Para los que deseen este es el OS que estoy usando [Deepin](https://www.deepin.org/), esta bueno el OS pero le falta actualizar sus repositorios y el único detalle es que no me permite agregar mas repositorios.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO! Creo que deberías colocar el comando que estás ejecutando.

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida, acabo de editarlo... espero tu apoyo.